# Rkhunter warning: file properties have changed

Tags: 16.04, server, rkhunter

I am testing `rkhunter` on a Ubuntu server 16.04 in Virtualbox.
The 11th of October I received an email alert from `rkhunter` inviting me to "Please inspect this machine, because it may be infected".

So I made a scan with `rkhunter` and found the following result:

```
$ sudo rkhunter -c --rwo
Warning: The file properties have changed:
         File: /usr/bin/curl
         Current hash: f025f2f2dca226c921b2b09da78b220656c098652d41c8654dc4853ff3fd1e5a
         Stored hash : cf846b7f3f11fc8af6cf79a2bbad3c8314eec72c1425b49bc9e34cf85a5090bb
         Current inode: 661569    Stored inode: 661888
         Current file modification time: 1507203916 (05-Oct-2017 13:45:16)
         Stored file modification time : 1478126766 (02-Nov-2016 23:46:06)
```

So I decided to check the `curl` package:

```
$ dpkg -S curl
$ echo $?
0
```

As you can see nothing was reported. 
I read [a discussion at serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/372271/411830) where it was suggested to check if the hash change was due to an automatic security update. 
Checking `/var/log/apt/history.log` I noticed that there was an unattended-upgrade of `curl` starting in 2017-10-11. 
I wonder: why rkhunter reports 05 October as the file modification date while the upgrade was made the 11 October?

Comment: Perhaps it's when the binary was created, before it was added to your system on October 11?

Comment: I do not know, I did not manually install `curl`, it was installed when I installed the server. I have an alert from OSSEC about Integrity checksum changed for: `/usr/bin/curl` the 11th of October: I understand this alert.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you update executable files via `apt update && apt upgrade` but the dabatase of rkhunter is not updated accordingly.

Either do it **manually** with:

```
sudo rkhunter --update --propupd
```

after every `apt update && apt upgrade`

or **automatically**:

In `/etc/rkhunter.conf` set

```
PKGMGR='DPKG'
```

and in `/etc/default/rkhunter` set

```
APT_AUTOGEN="true"
```